# Get current model id in odoo 8

Tags: model, odoo-8

I wish to get model id of `crm.helpdesk` in controller `main.py` file. I don't know how to get it. please suggest any solution. Thanks

Comment: model id for crm.helpdesk will be model_crm_helpdesk i guess

Answer (score 0):

in main.py you can inherit the the crm.helpdesk

```
class crm_helpdesk(models.Model)
_inherit= 'crm.helpdesk'
```

and in xml file you can inherit in a record tag for that you will be needing the external id which you can get by going into developer mode and selecting the manage views option from the dropdown debug menu.

```
<record id="external_id" name="">
  <field name="name">name</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="external_id"/>
```